# What kind of parameter should I be passing to my merge function in Bottom Up Merge Sort?

Tags: c, mergesort

I currently have this C code question and I am a bit confused as to how to put the parameters in it.

Q) Using C code complete the mergesort function shown below, your function must be implemented iteratively. You can assume the existence of a merge function with the following header and call it(You do not have to write the merge function).

So far I was given this:

```
void merge(int arr[], int start, int mid, int end);

void mergesort(int arr[], int len)
{

  // write code here
}
```

Here is my progress where I did some research and found out that the iterative way of doing merge sort was actually called Bottom Up Merge Sort.:

```
void mergesort(int arr[], int len)
{
    int windows;

    for (windows = 1; windows < len; windows = 2* windows)
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i+ 2*windows)
        {
            // not sure what to pass for the remaining parameters.
            merge(arr, i, ??, ??)); 
        }
    }   
}
```

What I have envisioned is that I would combine adjacent elements each time from 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ect ect(according to youtube) with the merge function that we "assume" exists. Can someone explain to me what I should be passing to the merge function for the remaining parameters? This is assuming we have already written a merge function that successively combines adjacent elements (windows).I know this requires some sort of logical math, but I am weak in math and coincidentally I am taking Calculus right now as well..

Comment: Take a look at ***[this](http://www.cquestions.com/2011/07/merge-sort-program-in-c.html)*** example of a merge sort implementation in C...

Comment: Hmm, doesn't that implementation combine both the `mergesort()` and `merge()` into one function? Take a look at an overview [**Merge Sort**](http://geeksquiz.com/merge-sort/). Since you are given `len`, split the array from `0<=len/2, and len/2+1 <len`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are passing an array which has size of a power of two this should work:

```
void mergesort(int arr[], int len)
{
    int windows;

    for (windows = 1; windows < len; windows = 2* windows)
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i+ 2*windows)
        {
            // not sure what to pass for the remaining parameters.
            merge(arr, i, i+windows, i+2*windows)); 
        }
    }   
}
```